# Knockout attr bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding

I am trying to add a class from a computed observable but I keep getting an undefined error. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the data binding:

```
<div data-bind="if:lcmsViewModel.lcms_instruments().hasOwnProperty('INSTR103')">
<instrument class="offset-2" data-bind="attr: { class: lcmsViewModel.lcms_instruments().INSTR103.color_class }">77</instrument>
</div>
```

Here is the model:

```
var InstrumentModel = function() {
    this.batch_id             = ko.observable()
    this.completion_time      = ko.observable()
    this.completed            = ko.observable()
    this.position             = ko.observable()

    this.time_left = ko.pureComputed(function(){
        var then = moment(this.completion_time()).utc().format("X")
        var now  = moment().local().format("X")

        var time_remaining = then - now;
        var hours = Math.floor((time_remaining/60)/60);
        return hours;
    }, this)

    this.time_class = ko.pureComputed(function(){
        if(this.time_left() > 6) {
            return 'lightgreen'
        } else if (this.time_left() < 6 && this.time_left() > 4) {
            return 'green'
        } else if (this.time_left() < 4 && this.time_left() > 0) {
            return 'darkgreen'
        } else {
            return 'blank'
        }
    }, this)
}
```

If I do I get the correct result and it is not undefined:

```
lcmsViewModel.lcms_instruments().INSTR1.time_class()
```

But when the page loads I get the following error:

```
knockout-3.2.0.js:63 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "attr: function (){return { class:lcmsViewModel.lcms_instruments().INSTR1.time_class} }"
Message: Cannot read property 'time_class' of undefined
```

Comment: Looks like `INSTR1` is `undefined`. Make sure you're assigning an instance of `InstrumentModel` to that property.

Comment: It is only undefined when binding. When I examine the models through console i.e. "lcmsViewModel.lcms_instruments().INSTR1.time_class()" the value is there and not undefined.

Comment: Under what circumstances? It's completely possible that you don't assign anything to the variable until after the binding has taken place.

Comment: Literally dude I am dumping the $data and it's right there. The binding is the problem.

Comment: Literally I'm telling you I work with Knockout almost every single day and it sounds like you aren't setting the data before the binding occurs. It is literally impossible for it to be an object and undefined at the same time and it isn't the binding that's causing that. `INSTR1` is either is `undefined` or it isn't.

Comment: If I add a <span> tag above INSTR1 and add the binding "if" to check if INSTR1 exists the error goes away...

R U SURE??

Comment: Holy crap look at my edited binding in the post now, that is what got it to work.

Comment: If your edit works, then you had a typo (`INSTR1.time_class` vs `INSTR103.color_class`)

Comment: Great if you got your html bindings to work, but please for everyone's sanity - especially your own - convert to something like:

    <div data-bind="if: showInstrument">
        <instrument class="offset-2" data-bind="attr: { class: colorClass }">77</instrument>
    </div>

Comment: Also, I don't know if it is intentionally, but have in mind that the "attr" binding that sets the "class" value, will overwrite the class="offset-2" value.